# How to access the device photos from web app (Any OS)

Tags: android, ios, web-applications, windows-mobile, iphone

I know that you cannot access the photos folder in a web app on Apple devices but does anyone know if ANY device allows this? eg: Android phone or tablet, Windows phone or tablet etc

Is there any way at all to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not that I'm aware of, and I've built over 100 mobile systems on everything from Palm, BlackBerry, Windows (all variants), Symbian, iOS, and Android.  Generally speaking web apps do not work well if they need to interface with host hardware components directly as the security of most browsers was designed from the beginning to not allow this.